# How can I find out the most likely dividend and divisor if I know the percentage distruibution?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I found a table in a report look like below:

Screenshot:
[image: some distribution].

I didn't see actual dividend and divisor, only the percentage.

How can I find out the most likely dividend and divisor?
Note:

1. Both the divisor and the dividend are integers.
2. There is rounding involved.
3. I added the last row to ensure that the sum of all percentages equals 100%.

Comment: the percentages are : 28.03%, 16.67%, 6.06%, 6.06%, 6.06%, 4.55%, 2.27%, 2.27%, 2.27%, 2.27%, 23.49%

Comment: Your question isn't formulated very precisely, but I assume you mean this: "Every number in this list is a fraction of two integers $\frac{a}{b}$, possibly rounded off. What are the most likely candidates for $a$ and $b$?"

Comment: Firstly, it is impossible to answer this completely, since there will always be infinitely many choices given that we are rounding the numbers. Furthermore, a question for you: Are you assuming that the denominator is the same in each number, i.e. the numbers are $\frac{a_1}{b},\frac{a_2}{b},\dots,\frac{a_n}{b}$ such that $a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=b$?

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim  1 That's what I mean, and I want to find the smallest  a and b; 2 denominator is the same in each number, and a1 + a2 + ... + an = b

Comment: Under this assumption, the reduced denominator seems to be $132$. Here we have $37/132 = 0,2803$, $22/132= 0,1667$, $8/132=0,0606$, $6/132=0,0455$ and $3/132 = 0,0227$ when rounded. Your added number to the table to make it equal $100$% cannot be described as a fraction of $132$, but this is just a relic of the rounding.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim  Wow, it's impossible,  how do you get it ?

Comment: A good recipe is to look at the smallest number, and then look at the ratios between the numbers. This ratio must always be a fraction. Taking $0,0227$, we see that its inverse is $44,05...$, which is a good approximation of $44$. This is our denominator for now. Now, $4,55/2,27\approx 2$, but $6,06/2,27 = 2,6696.. \approx 2,666... = \frac{8}{3}$. This shows that $0,0606$ is badly approximated as a fraction with denominator $44$, and suggested that I need to multiply my previous denominator by $3$, to $132 = 44\cdot 3$. Then I just checked the rest of the numbers have nice representations.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim Great solution！I originally planned to write a brute-force script.

Comment: I would recommend **not** to insert the last row, because rounding is likely to cause the percentages for all categories not to add to exactly $100\%$. Hence if you assume they do add exactly, you are likely writing down a wrong approximation for the last category's percentage.